# Como somar quantidade iguais SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.CtrlCargaNum, ITEM_PED_VENDA.PedVendaNum, 
PRODUTO.ProdCodEstr, PRODUTO.ProdNome, Sum(ITEM_PED_VENDA.ItPedVendaQtd) AS 
QtdItem FROM ITEM_PED_VENDA, CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA, PRODUTO
WHERE CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.PedVendaNum = ITEM_PED_VENDA.PedVendaNum
AND ITEM_PED_VENDA.EmpCod = CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.EmpCod
AND ITEM_PED_VENDA.ProdCodEstr = PRODUTO.ProdCodEstr
AND CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.EmpCod = '01'
AND CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.CtrlCargaNum = '0000038'
GROUP BY 
CTRL_CARGA_PED_VENDA.CtrlCargaNum,PRODUTO.ProdNome, ITEM_PED_VENDA.PedVendaNum, PRODUTO.ProdCodEstr, ITEM_PED_VENDA.ItPedVendaQtd
```

Funciona perfeitamente, como que eu faço para ele somar os produtos que possuem valores iguais e deixar somente um único nome?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não seria o caso de corrigir o nome que está errado?

Comment: Já tentei não deu certo

Comment: Se tirar o nome dá certo mas eu preciso do nome

Comment: coloca um MAX ou MIN no nome, e tira ele do group by... rsrs também nao pode ter "codprodest" né... e se são produtos diferentes, não tem o porque de somar...

Comment: É exatamente o que eu pensei @RovannLinhalis

Answer (score -1):

Olá,
você precisará deixar estes dois com o mesmo nome, depois disso você apenas precisa fazer um group by.

```
select prod_nome, sum(qtde) from teste group by prod_nome
```

Ao fazer isso, além de somar estes dois desejados também irá somar com o id de venda '0052887'. Se desejar somar somente os dois específicos precisa determinar um nome igual a apenas estes, para que seja reconhecido no group by.

Comment: São dois produtos diferentes ...